# rails-api ember js polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, polymorphic-associations

On  my Rails Api, I have 3 models User, Property, and Address. Each Users and Properties can have one Address and Address is set as a polymorphic association as following:

address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :locatable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In my `addresses` I have following fiels: `locatable_type` and `locatable_id` as well as the necessary fields for the address body.

My specs are passing on the rails side but when I am having hard to implementing this association in Ember. I use the ActiveModelSerializer gem on the rails side and the ActiveModelAdapter on the ember side.

So, I was wondering whether someone could point me to the direction to follow in order to getting these associations set in Ember.

Thanks,

Comment: answer for similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30833875/4950029

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has effectively helped me